# Prestashop 1.6 API - POST with json

Tags: json, web-services, prestashop

I'm using **Prestashop 1.6.1.1 web service** and I need to send *POST request* with json content. Is there any way to achieve this? When I performed *GET request* and I added `output_format=JSON` parameter, I got json as a result. Is there any analogical parameter for input?

Comment: Any success with this  ?

Comment: I looked into the prestashop sources and found out that JSON is available only in GET methods.

Comment: any chances when they'll provide JSON facility in PUT method @Mrk?